Lentitud en navegación y fetch API en aplicación Next.js del lado del cliente
Estoy experimentando problemas de rendimiento en mi aplicación Next.js, principalmente en dos áreas: la navegación entre páginas y las solicitudes fetch a mi API. La navegación entre las páginas es lenta, y las solicitudes fetch también tardan mucho en responder. Mis componentes son mayormente del lado del cliente debido a la necesidad de interacción por parte del usuario.
Código relevante:
src -> views -> apps -> enterprise -> list -> EnterpriseListTable.tsx
File: EnterpriseListTable.tsx

'use client'

// Imports.......


declare module '@tanstack/table-core' {
  interface FilterFns {
    fuzzy: FilterFn<unknown>
  }
  interface FilterMeta {
    itemRank: RankingInfo
  }
}

type EnterprisesTypeWithAction = EnterprisesType & {
  action?: string
}

const fuzzyFilter: FilterFn<any> = (row, columnId, value, addMeta) => {
  // Rank the item
  const itemRank = rankItem(row.getValue(columnId), value)

  // Store the itemRank info
  addMeta({
    itemRank
  })

  // Return if the item should be filtered in/out
  return itemRank.passed
}

// Column Definitions
const columnHelper = createColumnHelper<EnterprisesTypeWithAction>()

const EnterpriseListTable = () => {

  // States
  const [enterprises, setEnterprises] = useState<EnterprisesType[] | undefined>(undefined);

  // More states.......

  // Hooks

  // More hooks.......

  const setParametersToDelete = (parameters: {
    open: boolean,
    uid: string | null | undefined,
    name: string | null,
    code: string | null | undefined,
    isActive: boolean | null,
  }) => {

    setDeleteDialogOpen(parameters);
    setErrorDelete('');

  }


  const getEnterprises = async () => {
    setLoadingEnterprises(true);

    const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/enterprise`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    });

    const data = await res.json();

    const dataMap = data.enterprises.map((enterprise: EnterprisesType) => {
      return {
        ...enterprise,
        count: activeProductions(enterprise.uid, data.enterprises)
      }
    })

    setEnterprises(dataMap);
    setLoadingEnterprises(false);

    if (data.status === 200) {
      return data;
    }

    return null;
  }


  useEffect(() => {
    getEnterprises();
  },
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    [])

  // More methods.......

  const columns = useMemo<ColumnDef<EnterprisesTypeWithAction, any>[]>(
    () => [

      columnHelper.accessor('name', {
        header: 'Name',
        cell: ({ row }) => (
          <Link href={`/${locale}/enterprise/${row.original.uid}/productions`}>
            <Typography className='capitalize' color='primary'>
              {row.original.name}
            </Typography>
          </Link>
        )
      }),
      columnHelper.accessor('key', {
        header: 'Code',
        cell: ({ row }) => (
          <Typography className='capitalize' color='text.primary'>
            {row.original.key}
          </Typography>
        )
      }),
      columnHelper.accessor('isActive', {
        header: 'Active',
        cell: ({ row }) => (
          <div className='flex items-center justify-between mbs-3'>
            <Tooltip
              title={
                !row.original.isActive && row.original.lastDeactivation
                  ? `Enterprise Deactivated on ${format(new Date(row.original.lastDeactivation), 'MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a')}`
                  : ''
              }
              placement='bottom'
            >
              <Switch checked={row.original.isActive}

                onChange={() => showSwalChangeActive(row.original)}

                sx={{
                  '& .MuiSwitch-switchBase.Mui-checked': {
                    color: '#28c76f',
                    '&:hover': {
                      backgroundColor: 'rgba(76, 175, 80, 0.1)',
                    },
                  },
                  '& .MuiSwitch-switchBase.Mui-checked + .MuiSwitch-track': {
                    backgroundColor: '#28c76f',
                    opacity: 1,
                  },
                  '& .MuiSwitch-thumb': {
                    backgroundColor: '#fff',
                  },
                }} />
            </Tooltip>
          </div>
        )
      }),
      columnHelper.accessor('maxAllowedProductions', {
        header: 'Production',
        cell: ({ row }) => (
          <Typography className='capitalize' color='text.primary'>
            {row.original.count}
          </Typography>
        )
      }),
      columnHelper.accessor('educational', {
        header: 'Edu',
        cell: ({ row }) => (
          <div className='container-icon-check'>
            <div className={`div-circle circle-${row.original.educational ? 'true' : 'false'}`}></div>
            <div className='container-check'>
              <div className={`icon-check-item-${row.original.educational ? 'true' : 'false'}`}></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        )
      }),
      columnHelper.accessor('action', {
        header: 'Action',
        cell: ({ row }) => (
          <div className='flex items-center'>

            <OptionMenu
              iconClassName='text-[22px] text-textSecondary'
              options={[
                {
                  text: 'Edit',
                  icon: 'tabler-edit text-[22px]',
                  href: getLocalizedUrl(`enterprise/edit/${row.original.uid}`, locale as Locale),
                  linkProps: {
                    className: classnames('flex items-center bs-[40px] plb-2 pli-4 is-full gap-2 text-textSecondary')
                  }
                },
                {
                  text: 'Delete',
                  icon: 'tabler-trash text-[22px]',
                  menuItemProps: {
                    className: 'flex items-center gap-2 text-textSecondary',
                    onClick: () => setParametersToDelete({
                      open: true,
                      uid: row.original.uid,
                      name: row.original.name,
                      code: row.original.key,
                      isActive: row.original.isActive,
                    }),
                  },
                },
                {
                  divider: true,
                  dividerProps: { className: 'margin-simple' }
                },
                {
                  text: 'Permissions',
                  icon: 'tabler-shield text-[22px]',
                  menuItemProps: {
                    className: 'flex items-center gap-2 text-textSecondary',
                    onClick: () =>
                      openPermissionsDialog(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(row.original.permissions)), row.original.uid),
                  },
                },
                {
                  text: 'Productions',
                  href: getLocalizedUrl(`enterprise/${row.original.uid}/productions`, locale as Locale),
                  icon: 'tabler-chevron-right text-[22px]',
                  linkProps: {
                    className: classnames('flex items-center bs-[40px] plb-2 pli-4 is-full gap-2 text-textSecondary')
                  }
                },
              ]}
            />

          </div>
        ),
        enableSorting: false
      })
    ],
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    []
  )

  const table = useReactTable({
    data: enterprises || [],
    columns,
    filterFns: {
      fuzzy: fuzzyFilter
    },
    state: {
      rowSelection,
      globalFilter
    },
    initialState: {
      pagination: {
        pageSize: 10
      }
    },
    enableRowSelection: true, //enable row selection for all rows
    // enableRowSelection: row => row.original.age > 18, // or enable row selection conditionally per row
    globalFilterFn: fuzzyFilter,
    onRowSelectionChange: setRowSelection,
    getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
    onGlobalFilterChange: setGlobalFilter,
    getFilteredRowModel: getFilteredRowModel(),
    getSortedRowModel: getSortedRowModel(),
    getPaginationRowModel: getPaginationRowModel(),
    getFacetedRowModel: getFacetedRowModel(),
    getFacetedUniqueValues: getFacetedUniqueValues(),
    getFacetedMinMaxValues: getFacetedMinMaxValues()
  })

  return (
    <>

      <div className='flex justify-between flex-col items-start md:flex-row md:items-center p-6'>
        <div className='flex items-center gap-2 mt-2 mb-2'>
          <Typography className='hidden sm:block'>Show</Typography>
          <CustomTextField
            select
            value={table.getState().pagination.pageSize}
            onChange={e => table.setPageSize(Number(e.target.value))}
            className='is-[70px]'
          >
            <MenuItem value='10'>10</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value='25'>25</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value='50'>50</MenuItem>
          </CustomTextField>
          <Typography className='hidden sm:block'>entries</Typography>
        </div>
        <div className='flex flex-col sm:flex-row is-full sm:is-auto items-start sm:items-center gap-4'>

          <Button
            variant='contained'
            startIcon={<i className='tabler-plus' />}
            onClick={() => setAddEnterpriseOpen(!addEnterpriseOpen)}
            className='mt-2 mb-2 is-full sm:is-auto'
          >
            Add
          </Button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className='overflow-x-auto' style={{ position: 'relative' }}>
        {loadingEnterprises && <LoadingTable message="Loading enterprises..." />}
        <table className={tableStyles.table}>
          <thead className={`${mode === 'dark' ? 'dark' : 'light'}`}>
            {table.getHeaderGroups().map(headerGroup => (
              <tr key={headerGroup.id}>
                {headerGroup.headers.map(header => (
                  <th key={header.id}>
                    {header.isPlaceholder ? null : (
                      <>
                        <div
                          style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}
                          className={classnames({
                            'flex items-center': header.column.getIsSorted(),
                            'cursor-pointer select-none': header.column.getCanSort()
                          })}
                          onClick={header.column.getToggleSortingHandler()}
                        >
                          {flexRender(header.column.columnDef.header, header.getContext())}
                          {{
                            asc: <i className='tabler-chevron-up text-xl' />,
                            desc: <i className='tabler-chevron-down text-xl' />
                          }[header.column.getIsSorted() as 'asc' | 'desc'] ?? null}
                        </div>
                      </>
                    )}
                  </th>
                ))}
              </tr>
            ))}
          </thead>
          {table.getFilteredRowModel().rows.length === 0 ? (
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td colSpan={table.getVisibleFlatColumns().length} className='text-center'>
                  No data available
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          ) : (
            <tbody>
              {table
                .getRowModel()
                .rows.slice(0, table.getState().pagination.pageSize)
                .map(row => {
                  return (
                    <tr key={row.id} className={classnames({ selected: row.getIsSelected() })}>
                      {row.getVisibleCells().map(cell => (
                        <td key={cell.id}>{flexRender(cell.column.columnDef.cell, cell.getContext())}</td>
                      ))}
                    </tr>
                  )
                })}
            </tbody>
          )}
        </table>
      </div>

      {enterprises != null && <TablePagination
        component={() => <TablePaginationComponent table={table} />}
        count={table.getFilteredRowModel().rows.length}
        rowsPerPage={table.getState().pagination.pageSize}
        page={table.getState().pagination.pageIndex}
        onPageChange={(_, page) => {
          table.setPageIndex(page)
        }}
      />}

      

    </>
  )
}

export default EnterpriseListTable



src -> app ->api -> enterprise -> route.ts
File: route.ts

import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

import firebase from '@/libs/firebase';

export async function GET() {
  try {
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    const enterprisesCollection = db.collection('enterprise');
    const enterprisesSnapshot = await enterprisesCollection.orderBy('name').get();

    const enterprises = [];

    for (const doc of enterprisesSnapshot.docs) {
      const enterpriseData = doc.data();
      const enterpriseId = doc.id;

      const productionsCollection = enterprisesCollection.doc(enterpriseId).collection('production');
      const productionsSnapshot = await productionsCollection.get();

      const productions = productionsSnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
        id: doc.id,
        ...doc.data(),
      }));

      const enterprise = {
        ...enterpriseData,
        uid: enterpriseId,
        maxAllowedProductions: enterpriseData?.maxAllowedProductions ?? 0,
        productions,
      };

      enterprises.push(enterprise);
    }

    return NextResponse.json({ enterprises });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching enterprises:', error);

    return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Error fetching enterprises' }, { status: 500 });

  }
}


He intenté al inicio que mi tabla esté del lado del servidor y se haga el fetch y todo antes de enviarle la página al cliente y ese enfoque fue bueno, por un lado el usuario ingresaba a la página donde estaba la tabla y cargaba la información super rápido, pero cuando agregaba un nuevo elemento, esa tabla no se actualizaba con el nuevo valor, porque por un lado la data inicial venía ya desde el servidor, y para que me mostrara la tabla con ese valor actualizado, debía recargar nuevamente la página y esa no es la idea, así que no sé como pueda soluciona esto. ¿Qué estrategias o prácticas recomendadas puedo implementar para optimizar la carga y la interactividad de los componentes del lado del cliente en Next.js, y reducir el tiempo de respuesta de las solicitudes fetch?


pero cuando agregaba un nuevo elemento, esa tabla no se actualizaba con el nuevo valor, cuando necesitas re-renderizar un server component necesitas usar server actions, ¿Usaste un server action?

Creo que no, muchísisimas gracias por mencionarlo, es la primera vez que uso Next.js. Entonces, desde un componente del lado del cliente, puedo ejecutar esa acción para renderizar los datos que se trajeron desde el lado del servidor?

Que versión de nextjs estas usando?

Estoy usando la versión 14.1.3 de Next.js
